# Django Templates Inclusion / Blocks

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following template structure:

**base.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**detail.html** extending base.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- filter side panel -->
    {% block filter_panel %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**list.html** extending base.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- filter side panel -->
    {% block filter_panel %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**filter.html:**

```
{% extends "detail.html" %}
{% block filter_panel %}
  ...
  ...
{% endblock%}
```

Now, I have implemented a filter panel which is invoked by a button using `onclick="filter_open()"`. The respective method is in an external JS file and basically opens a side panel:

```
function filter_open() {
  document.getElementById("filtersidebar").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("filtersidebar-outer").classList.add("fc-filters-overlay");
}
```

This filter, I want to make available on detail.html and list.html. So, I created a new file `filter.html`. Both, the `detail.html` and the `list.html` have a `{% block filter %}{% endblock %}` and in `filter.html` I add the functionality within the respective Django blocks.

The button however, now throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
  at filter_open (main.js:146)
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):158)
```

I guess this is because I moved the filter to 'filter.html'.

Comment: Can you post your templates instead of explaining what they do please?

Comment: @Selcuk ok, I have edited the original question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks what you need is to use the `include` tag instead of using template inheritance, i.e.:

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- filter side panel -->
    {% include "filter.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```